# Inner Join query on 2 different databases - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

We have 2 different databases that I'm trying query against each other with an inner join.

When I run the query from phpmyadmin, the query works perfectly.  However, when I attempt to put the query into a php page, I cannot get the line to work.  I assume I'm missing something in the mysql_select_db line where I reference the host/db/user/pass for the first database.

What am I missing here to get this query to function on the page?  Again, I'm confident the actual query works since it does run in phpmyadmin.

Thanks in advance as always.

Here's the code I'm working with....

```
$hostname_db = "123.456.78.910";
$database_db = "votes_db";
$username_db = "votes_dbuser";
$password_db = "password123";
$db = mysql_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db, true) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

$hostname_db2 = "123.456.78.910";
$database_db2 = "survey_db";
$username_db2 = "survey_dbuser";
$password_db2 = "password456";
$db2 = mysql_connect($hostname_db2, $username_db2, $password_db2, true); 

// trying to make this work, query ok in phpmyadmin, but not on the php page
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
$query_testdb3 = sprintf("SELECT votes_db.vote_table.vote_survey_id
FROM votes_db.vote_table 
inner join survey_db.survey_table 
ON votes_db.vote_table.vote_survey_id = survey_db.survey_table.survey_id
WHERE votes_db.vote_table.vote_survey_id = 1457 ");
$testdb3 = mysql_query($query_testdb3, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$row_testdb3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($testdb3);
$totalRows_testdb3 = mysql_num_rows($testdb3);
```

Comment: If you're using absolute db.table.field-type references, you actually don't need the default DB stuff - default DB applies only when you're doing `table.field` references - gotta know what DB you want that table from, after all.

Comment: Just a guess, but PhpMyAdmin is probably logging in as a superuser, and has privileges on all DBs and the votes user probably only has privileges on the votes DB.  Connect using root or grant privileges to one of the users and it may fix the problem.

Comment: Tim - you nailed it.  It was a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permissions problem.  The user that was connecting to the database didn't have the proper privliges.  Hosting company fixed this for me, so I can't tell you exactly what they did, but it now works.

Tim was correct, it was working from phpmyadmin since I was logged in as a superuser...

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago I have the same issue ([mysql-php multiple databases problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726139/php-multiple-databases-problem))

So, remove the "true" option on the second ($db2) and everything should be fine.

Gl

Comment: Removing the 'true' didn't fix it, but I changed the order of those 2 things just for the heck of it, and it worked...sort of.  I'm getting permission errors now, but it seems to have done something.  Maybe fixing the permissions will fix the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: It was the permissions.  Reversing the order of those 2 things may have impacting the user it was trying to connect with, which could be why that changed things for you (and me), but ultimately, it was a permissions problem that the hosting company fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$`totalRows_testdb3 = mysql_num_rows($testdb3);`
```

change the column # in "$testdb3" in the last line to "$row_testdb3".

```
$totalRows_testdb3 = mysql_num_rows($row_testdb3);
```

Also if you put each $db and db2 in separate class and function with a:

```
mysql_close($db);
```

after each query.